# Java Decompiler for Eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, decompiler

I have tried both JadClipse and JD-Eclipse plugin but none seems to work every time I open a class file It says "Source not found".

Both my *.class and *.class(without source) are by default set to 'JD-Eclipse' but it doesn't seem to work, Has anyone else tried this or both these plugins are deprecated now?

Below is my environment:

Eclipse: Kepler
JDK: 7

Comment: [JadClipse for Eclipse 4.x 4.0.0](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jadclipse-eclipse-4x) is supposed to work.  In the future, links to specific versions of Eclipse plug-ins would be helpful in helping you diagnose problems.

Comment: I imported a war file in my eclipse project explorer...seems the class files I am trying to open are not in the project build path '"Alice/build/classes/com/complaintsystem/utility [in ComplaintmanagenentSystem] is not on its project's build path"

Comment: So it seems that I somehow need to put the classes in the build path...trying to figure out how!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working finally after putting the classes in the WEB-INF folder. Cheers!

Comment: Did you create a web-inf folder? I want to run a jar and decompile at debug time - do I have to create a web-inf folder inside the jar?

Comment: Jars could be de-compiled from Java Resources>>Libraries

Answer (score 5):

You may also want to use Java decompilers in the cloud, no installation, no Eclipse required:  http://www.javadecompilers.com/

Comment: Thanks for this but what if I want to decompile a whole pack of .class files?

Comment: Yes, probably it is not a solution then. The site works with .jar and .class only. I am not sure it is worth making a jar and uploading it... But still it may be done...